# USB speed test between C# application and USB device

Tags: c#, usb, communication

I have a C# application that connects to a custom USB device and I'm not happy with the USB speed. The communication works in a way that one side sends data and the other side acknowledges (AK) or rejects (NAK) the packages.

Now I want to check if the bottleneck is the device or the application in terms of processing speed.

Current ideas:
1) create a fake device as another C# application: Write a C# application that sends data via a USB port on another computer or the same computer. Is that even possible? As far as I understand, that application would need to register via USB on the other machine as a USB device.

2) Virtual USB device via UDE: just emulating the custom USB device to test processing capabilities of the application.

3) Wireshark for USB traffic (but then I don't know if the device just won't send faster because the application can't process fast enough).

Does anyone have already experience testing the speed between USB devices and C# applications? 
(and I specifically don't mean flash drives, it's not about the read/write on a drive, but a custom device).

What would be the way to do it?
Is 1) even possible?

Comment: I'd first of all introduce logging/unit testing to determine that the bit that's slow is definitely the low-level USB comms (i.e. your processing completes very quickly and then has to hang around waiting for responses from the device)... simply because that's the easiest to do.  Once you know the USB comms is the problem (from the c# app POV), then you know it's either the USB access or the device itself.

Comment: Oh, and for the record I don't have any USB-based experience, but have a lot of RS232 serial based experience